# Does buddypress require a theme to work?

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I am new to wordpress/buddypress. I have windows 7, WP v4.2 and BP v2.2.3.1. I am testing on localhost machine and have also setup a virtual host: buddypress.local:1234/WP

After activating buddypress (i have set the permalinks to other than default and checked anyone can register), when I try to register, the page just refreshes with all fields filled and the passwords fields reset to empty. How can I fix this? I have the default theme twentyfifteen enabled.

Further, any ideas on how can I test buddypress features? Do I need a buddypress compatible theme which exposes buddypress features in WP? Or can I use the default twentyfifteen theme to test buddypress features like groups, profile, notifications etc.

Comment: i log out and then click the register button, then fill the registration form and then click complete registration, and the page refreshes, and all the pre-filled fields are there except empty password fields.

Answer (score 1):

1) your are logged in that's why you are getting all field allready filled except password.

2) buddy press is compatible with all themes there is no specific theme for this .

3) If you have buddy press installed then check your admin dashboard there should page with title `Activity` View it . This will display the buddypress activities . for more information follow. [Link here](https://codex.buddypress.org/)

try to hit the url `www.yourdomain.com/activity/`

**Note**

Buddy press will not work with default permalink structure . Your permalink structure should be `Postname`

Comment: open register link in different browser. and check

Comment: i just checked the html of the register page...the signup form doesnt have an action associated with it. Please see below:
**<form action="" name="signup_form" id="signup_form" class="standard-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">**